# Find string after "task-" in a long substring using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have list of files with a pattern `sub-*_task-XYZabc_run-*_bold.json` and `sub-*_task-PQRghu_bold.json`, for example:

```
sub-03_task-dis_run-01_bold.json
sub-03_task-dis_run-02_bold.json
sub-03_task-dis_run-03_bold.json
sub-03_task-dis_run-04_bold.json
sub-03_task-dis_run-05_bold.json
sub-03_task-dis_run-06_bold.json
sub-03_task-fb_run-01_bold.json
sub-03_task-fb_run-02_bold.json
sub-03_task-fb_run-03_bold.json
sub-03_task-fb_run-04_bold.json
```

I intend to find all different task names from the filename. In the above example, `dis` and `fb` are the two  tasks.

What kind of regex should I use to find `TASKNAME` from `task-TASKNAME` in a given filename?

Comment: The kind that *you write yourself*. I find https://regex101.com useful, and [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) are always available. If you literally just want the string between `task-` and `_run`, that's trivial.

Answer (score 2):

The following *regex* should do it :

```
(?<=task-).*?(?=_)
```

*see [**regex demo / explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/9ThBEJ/1)*

**python** ( [demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbFVpNC00REhXV0U) )

```
import re
regex = r"(?<=task-).*?(?=_)"
str = """sub-03_task-dis_run-01_bold.json
         sub-03_task-dis_run-02_bold.json
         sub-03_task-dis_run-03_bold.json
         sub-03_task-dis_run-04_bold.json
         sub-03_task-dis_run-05_bold.json
         sub-03_task-dis_run-06_bold.json
         sub-03_task-fb_run-01_bold.json
         sub-03_task-fb_run-02_bold.json
         sub-03_task-fb_run-03_bold.json
         sub-03_task-fb_run-04_bold.json"""
matches = re.finditer(regex, str)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1
    print ("{match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```

Comment: ``TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-a8215bf33da9> in <module>()
     12        "sub-03_task-fb_run-04_bold.json")
     13 # str = files
---> 14 matches = re.finditer(regex, str)
     15 for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):

/Users/suyashdb/anaconda/lib/python3.5/re.py in finditer(pattern, string, flags)
    218 
    219     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 220     return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
    221 
    222 def compile(pattern, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @learnningprogramming code is working fine. check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQkc5Zkpqdmd4VDA)

Comment: the issue is, the str in your code is not a list of strings. I have changed str and now its broke again. Check here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQkc5Zkpqdmd4VDA

Comment: @learnningprogramming oh.. my bad. check updated answer now. it should work fine.